# Swift - Adding constraints to UIContainerView makes the container disappear

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uicontainerview

Im trying to display a UIContainerView to be the shop on a page of my app. This can be seen here:

[image]

The constraints acting on it are Horizontally in container and Vertically in container.

Nothing is shown in the simulator as shown below:

[image]

However, with constraints off it is shown, but I need constraints so it is in the right place on various devices:

[image]

Comment: Use Xcode's View Debugging feature to see the size and location of your view at run time.  If it's misplaced, you can inspect the constraints to see what is being applied.

Comment: Please share the constraints you currently have in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this but for anyone else with a similar problem.

The UIContainerView has to have size constraints on it.

This can either be done as the width and height or the space between each edge of the UIViewContainer and the border of the entire UIViewController.